# What is the reason for list content disappears after filter in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, filter, iterator, iterable

I am using python 3.6.9.

Since version 3.x, built-in function filter() returns an iterable filter object, instead of a list. In the first example, I use consequtive filters on a list, without casting filter objects to list:

```
>>> test1 = lambda n: n%2
>>> test2 = lambda n: n%3
>>>
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> filtered1 = filter(test1, my_list)
>>> filtered2 = filter(test2, filtered1)
```

This way, filtered2 yields 1 and 5, which is desired. In the second example, I try to overwrite my_list variable with the filtered iterable, and move on to the next filter the same way.

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_list = filter(test1, my_list)
>>> my_list = filter(test2, my_list)
```

my_list in the second line yields 1, 3, 5, as expected. However, my_list in the third line is empty.

```
>>> list(my_list)
[]
```

Documentation on filter states:

> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression (item for item in iterable if function(item))

So I made a try:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> my_list = (item for item in my_list if test1(item))
>>> my_list = (item for item in my_list if test2(item))
```

This way, my_list yields 1, 5 at the end, so it is not equivalent.
What causes the content of my_list in the second example to disappear?

Comment: `my_list in the second line yields 1, 3, 5, as expected.` How are you testing that? `filter()` returns a generator, so if you looked at the values with `list(my_list)` after the second line, you likely exhausted it.

Comment: It seems you are right. I exhausted it with printing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like when you implemented method 2 where you tried to overwrite
>   my_list variable with filter()'s result; when you checked for value of
>   my_list in step2, you exhausted your iterator my_list.
>
> Then in step3 you were passing empty iterator to filter method and
>   thus the output iterator was empty as well.

Below, I tried implementing the same without exhausting the list variable and got the desired output.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a = filter(test1, a)
>>> a = filter(test2, a)
>>> f(a)
1
5
>>> f(a)
>>>
```

f() is simply a function to print an iterator.
Notice how I exhausted my iterator using f(a) the first time by looping through it.
The next time i tried that, the iterator was empty.

```
>>> def f(obj):
...     for i in obj:
...             print(i)
...
```